# When trying to deploy to S3 on Circle CI, error is `The user-provided path build does not exist.`

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm trying to set up continuous deployment on Circle CI.

I've successfully run my build script, which creates a build folder in the root directory. When I run the command locally to sync with s3, it works fine. But in Circle CI I can't get the path to the build folder.

I've tried ./build, adding `working_directory: ~/circleci-docs` in the deploy job, and printing the working directory in a test run, which was **/home/circleci/project**, so I tried manually using **/home/circleci/project/build** and that didn't work either.

This is my CircleCI config.yml file:

```
executors:
  node-executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.8
  python-executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7

jobs:
  build:
    executor: node-executor
    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Run build script
          command: |
            curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
            yarn install --production=false
            yarn build

  deploy:
    executor: python-executor
    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Install awscli
          command: sudo pip install awscli

      - run:
          name: Deploy to S3
          command: aws s3 sync build s3://{MY_BUCKET}

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
```

The error message was:

The user-provided path build does not exist.

Exited with code 255

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work!

In the build job I used **persist_to_workspace** and the deploy job **attach_workspace** (both are under **steps**)

```
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/
          paths:
            - project/build

      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/
```

Comment: I guess it's important to point out the `version` that you might have used in your configuration, which I assume it was the `2`. I had the same problem as you, and when I tried to install `awscli` in the deploy step using the `python-executor`, circleci did not like it... Apparently, in the version 2.1, circleci does not accept `executor`/`docker` in the deploy step, only in `build`.